# Facebook API Get Last Events

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm trying to use the Facebook API to get the latest events from two of my Facebook pages. Any tip as to where I need to start?

I saw the Webhooks part, but I'm not really sure if that's the correct section to do something like this.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for the Page object and its events endpoint yet?

Comment: Yeah. I discovered it just now, although I'm still trying to figure out how to start using this.

Comment: Well if you want to do it in JavaScript on the client side, you need to start by making the user login to Facebook - so that you get a user access token you can use for your API call. If you do not want that, then you can also use a page access token (if you have admin access to the pages), or your app access token (if the pages and events are public and not restricted) - but those two types of token should never be exposed in client-side code, so you would have to do that server-side.

Comment: I forgot to mention in the question, but I'm doing this is in Laravel. And since I don't want the Facebook login, I will use the Page access token. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found out where I need to start. Here are the links:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page - Page Object

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events/ - Events endpoints